# What the difference between a tuple with comma and without?

Tags: python

In Python what is the difference between these two tuples?

```
t = (1)
```

and

```
t = (1,)
```

Comment: The first is not a tuple, that's just a single integer, grouped by parentheses (and since there is no other expression here the parentheses are ignored). It is the **comma** that makes something a tuple (except for the empty tuple `()`)`. Parentheses are optional unless the commas could be interpreted as part of other, surrounding syntax (such as a call).

Comment: The first one is an integer, not a tuple. Tuples with 1 element **require** the comma.